# \Psr\Http\Message\RequestInterface error when using mpdf

Tags: mpdf

The error

> "Uncaught Error: Interface "Psr\Http\Message\RequestInterface" not
> found"

occurs whenever I try to create a PDF file from UTF-8 source using mpdf.

I am running WAMPserver 3.3.1 under Windows 11 64bit, with PHP 8.1.15 and mpdf 8.1.4. The error occurs in php\vendor\mpdf\mpdf\src\Http\Request.php on line 13. This file begins

```
<?php
namespace Mpdf\Http;
use Psr\Http\Message\StreamInterface;
use Psr\Http\Message\UriInterface;
/**
 * PSR-7 URI implementation ported from nyholm/psr7 and adapted for PHP 5.6
 *
 * @link https://github.com/Nyholm/psr7/blob/master/src/Uri.php
 */
class Request implements \Psr\Http\Message\RequestInterface
```

I have updated mpdf to the current version using composer 2.5.4, which appears to complete OK.

Can anyone suggest a cause and solution?

EDIT

The problem was resolved by stripping out the existing mpdf code and reinstalling the current version. It seems the composer upgrade failed for some reason.

Comment: What does `composer info psr/http-message` output? Are you using composer autoload? Show _your_ side of the code.